# InputAccessoryView's viewWillDisappear: method called early in iOS 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, inputaccessoryview, ios-9-beta5

I've ran into quite an unfortunate bug in iOS 9. It seems that when you set a `UITextField.inputAccessoryView`, that view's `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` methods are called prematurely (right when the keyboard finishes animating up).

I've included a gif to demonstrate the issue. When the view turns red is when its `viewWillDisappear:` method has been called. Oddly when you dismiss the keyboard, `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` are called again. However, `viewWillAppear:` is only called once.

**Has anyone run into a similar issue?** I use `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` to wind down the controller, and obviously an early call is causing unwanted behaviour.

Note: Below is how I create and set the accessory view. Nothing notable in AccessoryViewController.m. Reproduced the issue in a clean project. And it is not present on iOS 8.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (self.textField.inputAccessoryView == nil) {
        self.textField.inputAccessoryView = self.vc.view;
    }
    return YES;
}

- (UIViewController *)vc {
    if (!_vc) _vc = [[AccessoryViewController alloc] init];
    return _vc;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I am seeing the same thing with one of my inputAccessoryViews

Comment: Still an issue in iOS 9 GM seed. I've gone with a workaround that sets a BOOL on the inputAccessoryView from UITextFieldDelegate's `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method. Then in my `viewWillDisappear:` and `viewDidDisappear:` methods I check that the BOOL is set before winding down the controller.

Answer (score 0):

The `AccessoryViewController` is not stored strongly on the ViewController. Store it in an instance variable so it does not get cleaned up.

My solution (Swift):

`var accessoryView: AccessoryViewController! // works`

vs

`weak var accessoryView: AccessoryViewController!`

Comment: I am already storing the `UIViewController` strongly. And `UITextField's inputAccessoryView` is also creating a strong reference to that `UIViewController's` view so it shouldn't be getting trashed.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem and sadly this solution work for me.